# Filtering and mixing monads in Slick for comprehension and Cats

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, slick, scala-cats

I have the following objective:
Create a monad that adds an user with the following computation flow:

1. Check if an user exists with a specified e-mail, **if he doesn't** then :
2. Check if the credentials given are ok (password long enough, etc.). If they are ok, then:
3. Save the user to the DB

My first "draft" would be something like this:

```
val work: DBIO[UserId] = for {
   userO <- UserRepository.findByEmail(createdUser.email) //userO is Option[User]
   //This won't work cause Action.withFilter doesnt exist
   if userO.isEmpty 
   //as above, validate user actually returns an ValidateNel[String, User]
   if User.validateUser(createdUser.email, createdUser.password).isValid 
   //Returns DBIO[UserId]
   id <- UserRepository.save(createdUser)
} yield id
```

Any ideas what is the best way to write this down in one monadic computation that I can db.run(...)? I'm using Cats + Slick 3.0.
Also I've wrote a simple implicit dbioMonad from https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/scalaquery/HrvrvyEIopw if that helps.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: does findByEmail return DBIO[Option[User]]?

Comment: Yes, it gets "unpacked" into an Option[User] and I want the computation to continue if the Option fails/isEmpty

Comment: Do you really need to use for comprehension? Would solution without it be acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one doesn't use for comprehension, so let me know if that's acceptable.

```
val work: DBIO[UserId] = {
  UserRepository.findByEmail(createdUser.email).flatMap {
    case Some(_) => DBIO.failed(new Exception("Provided email is already taken"))
    case _ =>
      if(User.validateUser(createdUser.email, createdUser.password).isValid) {
        UserRepository.save(createdUser)
      } else {
        DBIO.failed(new Exception("User validation has failed"))
      }
  }.transactionally
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good I'll try it out. The only thing that stands out here is the "new Exception(...)" thingy and I want to keep it pure functional. Or is this basically the same as Nothing for the Option Monad?

Comment: `DBIO.failed(new Exception("..."))` basically means that if you'll execute this action (with `db.run(...)`, which returns a `Future[T]`) it will finish as a `Failure` (which is a subtype of the `Future`). You don't throw any exceptions here (that's why you still remain functional) - it's just a way of indicating that `DBIOAction` will finish as a `Failure`. The other one is `DBIO.successful(...)` which indicates that the action will finish as the `Success` subtype of the `Future`

Comment: One problem I got is that there isn't a .transactionally method on the work val. EDIT: Nvm forgot an import