# Slick update fields based on its context

Tags: scala, slick

I am new in Slick and scala and I have the following question.
I want to find if there is a record on my database based on the same timestamp. My table has (id, timestamp, steps, location, direction)

1.measurements.filter(_.timestamp === operated_item.timestamp) // where measurements is my TableQuery

2. if the record does not exist I want to make a creaton based on the documentation in slick
3. if the record exists then:

a. if the steps are already there I want to update the location and the direction

b. if the steps are not there, then I want to update the steps.

How can I do these steps, right now I have something like that:

```
def operation(user_id: Long, operated_item: measure) = {

val measurementsOperations = new MeasurementsOperations(db)

val q = for {
            c <- measurements.filter(_.timestamp===operated_item.timestamp).filter(_.steps =!= operated_item.timestamp)
        } yield (c.steps)
        val act = q.update(operated_item.steps)

        db.run(act)
 }
```

I think I have to do something like this: [Filtering and mixing monads in Slick for comprehension and Cats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37334335/filtering-and-mixing-monads-in-slick-for-comprehension-and-cats)

But I do not know how to create all the nests.

Comment: Have you heard Upsert in slick 3? This is a sample showing how to update a row using slick else create if non-existing.  And I believe in there are some sample conditional statement within slick Upsert query - http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2015/07/14/upsert.html

Comment: I saw the post on the link you provided me, I think I need something similar to Rolling Our Own Update.

Comment: Yes but if I want to update only one field and keep the other unchangable?